# Check fingerprints of server SSL/TLS certificates in http.NewRequest

Tags: ssl, go

How can I check the fingerprints of the server SSL/TLS certificates during a http request in golang?

This [ruby code](https://github.com/figo-connect/ruby-figo/blob/c8264fcd778f47e517d8e1675337fc4e29a2b6b5/lib/figo.rb#L69) shows what I want to do in Go:

```
  @verify_callback = proc do |preverify_ok, store_context|
    if preverify_ok and store_context.error == 0
      certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(store_context.chain[0])
      fingerprint = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(certificate.to_der).upcase.scan(/../).join(":")
      $valid_fingerprints.include?(fingerprint)
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

In general the process of generating a certificate fingerprint in Go is pretty simple. If you already have an `x509.Certificate` struct, stored in `cert`, all you need to do is

```
sha1Fingerprint := sha1.Sum(cert.Raw)
```

Getting certificates from an HTTP response struct after the request is complete is also pretty easy (use `resp.TLS.PeerCertificates`), but it doesn't seem like that's what you need.

If you need access to the server's certificate at TLS connection set up time, I think you'll need to create your own `http.Transport` and hand it a custom implementation of `DialTLS`. You'd then use that transport when configuring an `http.Client` to make your outbound requests.

Within your custom `DialTLS` func you'd have access to connection state information like the server's certificate chain, and you could perform the SHA1 fingerprint generation from there.

Comment: I have a self signed TLS certificate (tls.Certificate) that contains a Leaf (x509.Certificate). I use the tls.Certificate in a tls.Config for a http.Server. But the fingerprint calculated with sha1.Sum(cert.Leaf.Raw) doesn't match the fingerprint shown by my browser. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sha1.Sum(cert.Certificate[0]) worked, where the "derBytes" were the only element in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't implement certificate checking yourself, but let the net/http do the checking based on the valid CAs you provide. Also, usually working directly with fingerprints isn't worth the trouble.

For example, this is how you set up a HTTPS server that requires clients to authenticate by using a certificate. The client certificate must be signed by the CA, or the SSL/TLS handshake stops.

```
    // Server's own certificate & key
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.crt", "server.key")
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    // Load the CA certificate(s)
    capool := x509.NewCertPool()
    cacert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ca.crt")
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    capool.AppendCertsFromPEM(cacert)

    // Server configuration
    config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, ClientCAs: capool, ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert}
    config.NextProtos = []string{"http/1.1"}
    config.Rand = rand.Reader // Strictly not necessary, should be default

    // TLS web server
    myTLSWebServer := &http.Server{Addr: "myaddress", TLSConfig: &config, Handler: nil}

    // .. proceed with setting handlers etc
    http.HandleFunc("/", myHandler)

    // Bind to port and start the server up
    conn, err := net.Listen("tcp", settings.ServiceAddress)
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    tlsListener := tls.NewListener(conn, &config)
    myTLSWebServer.Serve(tlsListener)
```

Reading the documentation for [tls.Config](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) will show you that by changing the parameters (*ClientAuth, ClientCAs, Certificates, RootCAs*) you can easily select different modes for checking the certificates. You usually get failures returned in *error*.

If you really insist on checking fingerprints, you can retrieve the TLS status from Request [TLS *tls.ConnectionState](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ConnectionState). I think you should probably use the *Signature* from that struct for fingerprinting.. Off the top of my head, something roughly along the lines of

```
func lol(r *http.Request) {
    tls := r.TLS
    if tls != nil {
       // Try the first one for simplicity
       cert := tls.PeerCertificates[0]
       signature := cert.Signature
       // Do something with the signature
    }
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I think "how to compute a cert's fingerprint in Go" is still a valid question. :)

Comment: Agreed that fingerprint calculation is an important part of this question. See my answer for a solution. The suggestion in this answer to look at ```cert.Signature``` is incorrect.